# "Group By" on entities from document-based storage?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, group-by, ravendb

If this is a duplicate, I apologize; I have done my share of searching, but I have figured out what to search for.

Let's say you have a student database and you want to average their scores based on gender. With your standard issue relational database, this is pretty trivial. It might require a query with an explicit join, or you may just use navigation properties or something, but it's going to look a little like this:

```
var averageScore = db.Grades
    .Where(grade => grade.Student.Gender == selectedGender)
    .Average();
```

But what if you're connected to a document-based system and your data structure is, instead, just a Student object with a collection of Grade objects embedded in it?

```
var averageScore = db.Students.GroupBy(student => student.Gender)
    .ThisDoesNotWork(no => matter.What);
```

I have tried three dozen different ways to do a GroupBy that manages to transform collections of values into a single collection of values sharing a common key, but none of them have worked. Most of my attempts have involved attempting a SelectMany inside the GroupBy, and--if that's possible--let's just say that the compiler doesn't like my bedside manner.

Edit: Not sure what you mean by "format." The data structure we're talking about is just a class with a collection as one of its members.

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's the format of the document?

Comment: If your entity does not does not override Equals and GetHash it will not work. In a recent blog post I had a similar problem with ExpandoObjects http://wysnet.blogspot.com/2013/08/comparer-for-expandoobject.html. Could provide the code behind student?

Comment: Try using the aggregation framework from the console to see if you can get the output you want. If you can't, then there's not any hope of it working with LINQ. If you can -- then, you still can't use LINQ, but you'll at least be able to get the data you want.

Comment: It's never good to bet against linq. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) will flatten the collection for you.

```
var average = db.Students
    .Where(s => s.Gender == selectedGender)
    .SelectMany(s => s.Grades)
    .Average();
```

[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx), on the other hand, will group specific elements together.  So, if you want to group all by gender:

```
var averages = db.Students
    .GroupBy(
        s => s.Gender,
        (gender, group) => group
            .SelectMany(s => s.Grades)
            .Average());
```

"group" is an IEnumerable, ie. all the students that fit each group.

Comment: That actually doesn't work (compile time problem; maybe it would if you edited it slightly?), but I found something that does.

Comment: I was unable to get the compiler to accept the second lambda in the `GroupBy`, and I literally just copy/pasted from here to there--but that might have been the problem. My previous attempts had the wrong signature (only one input instead of two) and IntelliSense might have been bogged down thinking I hadn't changed that. At any rate, I never just tried hitting F5 because I'm goofy. Your answer works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rich's answer got me thinking a little harder about `SelectMany()` (plus I got off work and was bored), so I put in a little more work and here's what I've got:

```
var averagesByGender = db.Students
    .SelectMany(
        student => student.Grades,
        (student, grade) => new { Gender = student.Gender, Grade = grade })
    .GroupBy(
        record => record.Gender,
        record => record.Grade)
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, Average = group.Average() });
```

The `SelectMany()` works pretty much exactly like a join statement would in any SQL database: you get one record per grade with the associated student information, and from there you can query whatever you want to in the old-fashioned way (or, as in my example, you can get one result for each of the genders represented).

The only wrinkle is that, apparently, this is *too* relational... As in RavenDB refuses to try to translate it into a query. Luckily enough, that's irrelevant if you hide it behind `.ToList()`. Wonder if it will work the same way with MongoDB.

Comment: I have accepted Rich's answer. I was gonna delete this one, but I'm leaving it because--until yesterday--I didn't know that you could use `SelectMany` this way and maybe it'll help someone else at some point.